# Binding a key to be the Menu Key

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm aware there's a pretty popular way to rebind the capslock key, but is there any way to bind a key to be the Menu key? I use it quite often when I have one, and there's a key that I'd like to bind that functionality to. (in this case, the PrintSc button).

Comment: By `Menu` what do you mean? Or better, what program do you mean? Anyways, have you tried SharpKeys?

Comment: I mean the Windows menu key, that is built into most USB keyboards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key

Comment: You *can* do that from [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html)

Comment: @MichaelLawton Still not correct. You are thinking of the windows key, not the menu key. Check the link to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Thank you, found it. If you'd like, put that as an answer (maybe add a bit of detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use SharpKeys to bind the `PrntSc` to the `Menu/Application key` function:

1. Download [Sharpkeys 3.5](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html).
2. Install / Extract the .msi / .zip file.
3. Run SharpKeys. You should have the following window shown:

   [image: SharpKeys main window]
4. Press **Add**. Select on the left listbox the PrtSc button and on the right the Application button. Then press **OK**.

   [image: Sharpkeys add dialog]
5. Afterwards press **Write to Registry**. You may need to reboot your computer, as the settings are read on boot. And you're done.

   [image: SharpKeys end dialog]

Please refer to the SharpKeys FAQ for any additional problems you might encounter.